# report viewer on c# which is connected to ms access error on BETWEEN (SQL)

Tags: winforms, ms-access, reportviewer

Right I have a program which is for a warehouse. I am trying to use report viewer to display the information so the user can print them. in one of the forms the user can decide how many items to look at (between the date of x and y).

The problem that I am facing right now is that C# is giving me an error on:

```
internal void Fill(DataSetAllTheStock.DeliveryDataTable deliveryDataTable, string p, string p_2)
{
   throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

And the error is:

"NotImplementedException was unhandeled. The method or operation is not implemented."

```
InnerException = null
```

Do you have any idea what I can do? Because I need to use the reporter view and also I need the user to pick the dates.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, you are just throwing the error and not catching it.  You should do something like this instead:

```
internal void Fill(DataSetAllTheStock.DeliveryDataTable deliveryDataTable, string p, string p_2)
{
   try
   {
      // Do some things here.
   }

   catch (NotImplementedException exc)
   {
      // Handle the exception here.
   }

   catch (Exception exc)
   {
      // Or, handle the exception here.
   }
}
```

In the example above, note that I am catching two types of exceptions: 1) the most general 'Exception' type and 2) the more specific 'NotImplementedException' type.  Exception handling in C# goes from the *most specific* type to the *most general* type. Also, it seems it would do you some good to read up on [exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx).

Comment: but this is in a data set I can not do anything.

Comment: No, it's a `.Fill()` method being called to fill a dataset.  There is no reason why you couldn't add a `try/catch` to it.  Either that, or you haven't posted enough of your code to give the best answer possible to your problem.

Comment: can I have you email so I can send you some picture? from the form and the codE?

Comment: I can not find it here is mine. r.moghbel@hotmail.co.uk (thanks for the help)